# PHP Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$var in

Tags: php, json, properties

before create a new question i searched and searched here on SO and generally on Google, but i cannot figure out how to solve my problem. I'm creating a PHP file and I get this error:

**PHP Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$city in /my/path/www/myfile.php on line 517**

At line 517 i have the following `return`:

```
public static function getCity($jsondata) {
    return $jsondata->address->city;
}
```

If i add `print_r($jsondata); die();` to print the content of the JSON file, i get this:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [place_id] => 198765
    [lat] => 52.1987
    [lon] => 0.1365
    [address] => stdClass Object
        (
            [road] => Devonshire Road
            [suburb] => Petersfield Ward
            [city] => Cambridge
            [county] => Cambridgeshire
            [state_district] => East of England
            [state] => Inghilterra
            [country] => Regno Unito
            [country_code] => gb
        )
)
```

So, what's wrong with my code?

Comment: nothing, its just a notice not an error

Comment: What is the **exact** output of: `highlight_string(print_r($jsondata, TRUE));`

Comment: @Andrew No, `new` is just wrong and won't work. Also OP doesn't have to convert it into an array.

Comment: My guess would be you're calling getCity() in a loop, the item you print_r()ed above is the first one while the one causing the error is an item with an address without any city field present in your json data. Correct ?

Comment: Are you sure that's the right code? I can't replicate the issue: http://ideone.com/kGfwXZ

Comment: @Calimero I go for the guess, that OP maybe has some "hidden" characters in his property name, but the loop is also a good guess :)

Comment: I agree with @DamienPirsy - it works fine in tests here

Comment: @Lucky Erm, you're suggesting just because it's an error of severity *NOTICE* it is not worth investigating or fixing...?! O_o

Comment: @deceze there's lot more to worry about than a silly PHP notice. It comes at the very last in my todo list. Haven't even seen the entire process flow either. so, if its not affecting your app, ignore for now.

Comment: @Lucky *Any* notice or warning that PHP outputs is there to **point you to a bug in your code which produced a result you probably did not anticipate/expect/want.** Of course you investigate that! "Silly PHP" is trying to be helpful here and tell you that **your code is wrong**. If you want to run code **which is wrong**, be my guest; but don't be surprised about where the *actual* problems in your program's behaviour are coming from.

Comment: @Calimero is right. Thank you to all for your comments! I really appreciate them.

Comment: @deceze, agree with you about php trying to help but as I said, the notice is the last thing I look at. its just my preference. Oh! and sorry, I didnt mean silly php, I meant silly notice :)

Answer (score 0):

To print the Json file you need to add data after $jsondata variable

**`print_r($jsondata->data);`**